# Type Erasure for wildcards

Tags: java, generics

Given these lines of code, how are they type erased?

I understand that for this one, it goes as follows (correct me if i'm wrong please!):

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
// type erased to:
List l = new ArrayList();
```

But what about for these two?

```
List<? extends Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
// Does it get erased to:
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>(); ?
List<Object> l = new ArrayList<>();  ?
List l = new ArrayList();            ?

// Assume some generic class
List<? extends T> l = new ArrayList<>();
// Does it get erased to:
List<T> l = new ArrayList<>();       ?
List<Object> l = new ArrayList<>();  ?
List l = new ArrayList();            ?
```

If `? extends Integer` gets erased to `Integer`, why doesn't it get erased fully to `Object`, since `List<Integer>` gets erased to `List`? Or am I confused between `List<Object>` and `List`?

PS, confused with the whole type erasure with generics thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a parameterised type (in simple terms, a type with `<>`s at the end), it always erases to the non-parameterised type, so `List<Integer>`, `List<T>`, `List<? extends Integer>`, `List<? extends T>` *all* erases to `List`. It doesn't matter what you put in the `<>`.

You might have confused this with how *type parameters* erase. If you have a type parameter, such as the `T` here:

```
class Foo<T extends Integer> {
    private T bar;
}
```

`bar`'s type erases to `Integer`:

```
// after erasure
class Foo {
    private Integer bar;
}
```

Type parameters erase to the erasure of their (first) constraint. `T extends Integer` isn't a particularly useful constraint, so here's another example:

```
class Foo<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private T bar;
}
```

erases to:

```
class Foo {
    private Comparable bar;
}
```

`T` erases to the erasure of `Comparable<T>`. `Comparable<T>` erases to `Comparable`, so the type of `bar` is `Comparable`.

Further reading: [Java Language Specification section 4.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6)